# Changing google maps POIItem markers

Tags: swift, google-maps, markerclusterer

i'm building an iOS app where i'd like to change the default red google maps markers unfortunately I've tried to look all over the internet and cannot find any solutions. 
My problem is that i've implement the gmaps clustering with gmaps utils, but I can't seem to find a way to change the icon of an item of the class POIItem. When try to change the makers appearance both markers are displayed, the default and the custom.

So here's a code snippet : 
func getClubs(){

```
        ref.child("Clubs").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children{
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let value = snap.value as? [String: Any]
                //print(value!)
                let name = value?["Name"] as? String
                //let latitude = value?["Latitude"] as? String
                //let longitude = value?["Longitude"] as? String
                let contact = value?["Contact"] as? String
                let prix = value?["Prix"] as? [String:Int]

                var adresse = value?["Adresse"] as? String
                if adresse == nil {
                    adresse = value?["Address"] as? String
                }
                var idFB = value?["ID Facebook"] as? Int
                if idFB == nil {
                    idFB = value?["Facebook ID"] as? Int
                }

                //let clubFbId = String(describing: idFB)
                //print(clubFbId)
                print("\(idFB)")

                let clubStruct: Club = Club(name: name!, adresse: adresse!, contact: contact!, clubIdFb: idFB!)

                if prix != nil {
                    clubStruct.prix = prix
                }

                self.clubArray.updateValue(clubStruct, forKey: idFB!)
                print(self.clubArray[idFB!]?.name)
            }
        }){ (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        ref.child("Events").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            //var indice: Int = 1
            for child in snapshot.children{
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                //print(snap.key)
                let event = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "0").value as? [String:Any]
                let place = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "0").childSnapshot(forPath: "place").value as? [String:Any]

                let clubFbId = place?["id"] as? String

                let name = event?["name"] as? String
                let start_time = event?["start_time"] as? String
                let end_time = event?["end_time"] as? String
                let eventFbId = event?["id"] as? String
                let videoURL = event?["videoURL"] as? String
                let timetable = event?["timetable"] as? [String:String]

                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
                dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+2:00")

                let start = dateFormatter.date(from: start_time!)!
                let end = dateFormatter.date(from: end_time!)!

                if self.currentDate! > end {
                    continue
                }

                let location = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "0").childSnapshot(forPath: "place").childSnapshot(forPath: "location").value as? [String:Any]

                let latitude = location?["latitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees
                let longitude = location?["longitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees

                let eventStruct: Event = Event(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!, clubIdFb: clubFbId!, eventIdFb: Int(eventFbId!)!, name: name!, start: start, end: end, idFirebase: snap.key)

                if videoURL != nil {
                    eventStruct.videoURL = videoURL
                }

                if timetable != nil {
                    eventStruct.timetable = timetable
                }

                self.eventArray.updateValue(eventStruct, forKey: clubFbId!)
                //print(self.eventArray[clubFbId!]?.name)


                let event_marker = GMSMarker()
                let clubimage = UIImage(named: "clubmarker")
                let markerView = UIImageView(image: clubimage)
                markerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 58, height: 103)
                event_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)




                event_marker.map = mapViewFirst
                event_marker.iconView = markerView
                event_marker.isTappable = true
                event_marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
                let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
                let event_item = POIItem(position:position, marker: event_marker)
                self.clusterManager.add(event_item)
                self.clusterManager.cluster()
                //      var iconGenerator : GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator!
                //      let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: mapViewFirst, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)

                if event_marker.position.latitude == self.latitude{
                    event_marker.iconView?.tintColor = UIColor.red
                }

            }
        }){ (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
    print(eventArray)

    getClubs()
```

If anyone has a solution it would be highly appreciated i'm quite new to programming and it's been a while i'm stuck with this for a while.

[image: Below is a screenshot of my output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Google Documentation link: [Customizing Marker Clusters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering#customize-the-marker-clusters)

SO answer here in SWIFT:  Its not pretty but apprently works.

[How to implement GMUClusterRenderer in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547622/how-to-implement-gmuclusterrenderer-in-swift)

For other basic markers:

Documentation at Google for basic markers here is the link: 
[change the marker color](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#change_the_marker_color)

```
marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: .black)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i needed!